# Checking usage of the email templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, sfmc-business-unit, cleanup

I would like to know if it is possible to see in Marketing Cloud the count of emails that are using each email template. This is really useful, for example, when doing a clean-up of the Business Unit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [content builder API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_getObjectById) to fetch this information. When you hit the API, in response you will see the template used by the email.

You can write a SSJS script to store the email information along with the template information.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain it properly. I want it the other way around: from an email template, to list all the emails that are using it. Is it the same as what you shared?

Comment: Yeah, I think the idea @fromero is to regularly pull this information from Content Builder API, store it into a DE then use that DE to pull the template information via AMPscript/SSJS lookups or SQL, etc.  You unfortunately cannot do a filter level on the `view.html.template.id` or name in the CB Query API (or at least I have not found a functional way to date) so it would need to be a multi-step solution.